# connect to Remote server in vb script

Tags: vbscript, wmi

hi i have tried to connect to remote server in vbscript but i am getting the error 
2147023174 RPC server is not available. if tried to connect via remote desktop connection i am able to connect.please help me to reslove this issue.

```
enter code here

Dim strMachine="IP"

strAltDomain = "domail"
strAltUsername = "username"
strAltPwd ="*****"
Set objGlobalCIMV2Service = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strMachine, _
                "root\cimv2", strAltUsername, strAltPwd, "MS_409", "ntlmdomain:" + strAltDomain)    
             wscript.echo "Error connecting to specified computer: " & err.description & " error number="&err.number
 wscript.quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the firewall and set up the wmi remote access, try these articles from MSDN.

- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting to WMI Remotely Starting with Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting Through Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting Between Different Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: just tell at which machine i have to configure these settings.on my machine that have windows 7 or server that is windows 2003 server.

Comment: please read the documentation. most of settings must be done in the remote machine.