# How to log into user account?

Tags: vbscript

After someone has logged off (*Start button→Logoff*) for the night, at a certain time in the morning I want to have the Task Scheduler automatically log into the Windows 7 user account (the opposite of *Start button→Logoff*) that is password protected. The machine is 64 bit. I am doing this so systems (vbs, vba, etc.) can prep files prior to the user showing up to work.

I was pretty sure this was possible, but I can't find it anywhere online, so I am wondering if it really is possible.

I have to this in a VBScript.

For security reasons I need to log him off at night, but I figured that part out (vbs from SO):

```
Set = wshell = Wscript.CreateObject(Wscript.Shell")
wschell.exec("shutdown.exe -L -F") 'logoff and force shutdown programs
```

Edit1:
Using an answer from Sujith, I attempted to set this up. First I must point out that this is NOT a remote computer or connection. I'm trying to get the local computer to log back in to the user account.

I created logon.vbs with this vbs code:

```
Set = wshell = Wscript.CreateObject(Wscript.Shell")
wschell.exec("shutdown.exe -L -F") 'logoff and force shutdown programs

WScript.Sleep(5000)

computer = "computername"
username = "OTHERDOMAIN\user"
password = "password"

Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set wmi = locator.ConnectServer(computer, "root\default", username, password)
wmi.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
```

In other words, I am logging off and right back on (avoiding the Task Scheduler so things are simplified). I also tried a lot of variations on this trying to get it to work. It logs me off just fine, but nothing happens after that. I have to login manually.

I also tried the Task Scheduler setting mentioned in Sujith's answer, but it never turned on that I could tell.

Edit2: Or please tell me what you need to provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a task scheduler to run a vbscript, this task can be triggered while the user logs off from his session by selecting the trigger option "On disconnect from user session" & Any user.

The vbscript which is scheduled on trigger may have the code for remote login on the machine. For the code the below links will help you.

[connect to Remote server in vb script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416252/connect-to-remote-server-in-vb-script)

[Connecting to a Remote Server on a different domain -- how do I enter the username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976838/connecting-to-a-remote-server-on-a-different-domain-how-do-i-enter-the-userna)

Comment: I wasn't able to get the task to kick off after I logged off. Not even a failed run of the task. I'll add info to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. If you can do a reboot first, you can solve it by using Windows' built-in "Auto Logon" feature.

If so, I've got some suggestions for an alternate solution for you:

**Logging off users at a specified time**

---

- Follow the instructions for [Assigning Logon Hours](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781861%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Old article, but still valid for newer Windows Server OS.

  OR
- Create a script that logs off all logged on users, then create a scheduled task running as **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** to execute it at a specified time.

**Automatically rebooting and logging on with a specific username/password**

---

Create a batch file called, say, "Enable_AutoLogon_and_Reboot.cmd" and place it in a folder, e.g. "C:\BatchFiles". Contents:

```
set sUsername=SOMEDOMAIN\Someusername
set sPassword=somepassword

:: Enable autologon on next boot
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f

:: Set autologon to only log on once
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon" /v AutoLogonCount /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

:: Set username
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon" /v DefaultUsername /t REG_SZ /d "%sUsername%" /f

:: Set password
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d "%sPassword%" /f

:: Reboot
shutdown /r /t 0 /f
```

Replace the values of the variables at the start with the actual username and password.

Create a scheduled task running as **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** (e.g. running daily at 06:00):

```
schtasks /create /tn "\CustomTasks\Enable AutoLogon and Reboot" /tr "%comspec% /c C:\BatchFiles\Enable_AutoLogon_and_Reboot.cmd" /st 06:00 /sc DAILY /ru "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /f
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I will give this some thought, but I don't think rebooting is an option as that requires the user to have saved everything they were working on and/or accept that the current state of some files they were working on will be saved as-is.

Comment: If you're logging the user off at night using "shutdown.exe -L -F" you're already force-closing (-F) any running applications.